# Is the Terrorist Exclusion List (TEL) still used for anything?

Tags: united-states, terrorism

Section 411 of the USA PATRIOT ACT of 2001 (8 U.S.C. § 1182) authorized the Secretary of State, in consultation with or upon the request of the Attorney General, to designate terrorist organizations for immigration purposes. This authority is known as the [Terrorist Exclusion List (TEL)](http://www.state.gov/j/ct/rls/other/des/123086.htm) authority.

The TEL list has not been update since 2004.
Is it still used for any purpose?

Has it been sort of superseded by the [FTO list](http://www.state.gov/j/ct/rls/other/des/123085.htm) (which has a different definition, but is updated regularly)?

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm not sure it qualifies as "History"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the [Terrorism Exclusion List](http://www.state.gov/j/ct/rls/other/des/123086.htm) ("TEL") is still used. It has actually been updated with some regularity since its creation in 2001, most recently in 2012. The TEL is used to deny individual access at the immigration level. It is often referred to as a black list. The list [originally had 39 members](http://web.archive.org/web/20071012043928/http://state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2001/6695.htm), and is currently at 59 members. The State of Ohio has a nice [compilation of the different lists](http://www.csuohio.edu/sites/default/files/media/financial_aid/documents/terrorist_exclusion_list.pdf) that they use for security purposes.

In 2012, the State Department [removed](http://blogs.wsj.com/corruption-currents/2012/09/06/us-removes-nepalese-maoist-group-from-terror-list/) the [Communist Party of Nepal](http://www.cpnuml.org/en/) from the TEL. Furthermore, the TEL is referenced on a current Immigration Services [website](http://www.uscis.gov/portal/site/uscis/menuitem.eb1d4c2a3e5b9ac89243c6a7543f6d1a/?vgnextoid=27222356e0955310VgnVCM100000082ca60aRCRD&vgnextchannel=27222356e0955310VgnVCM100000082ca60aRCRD).

The TEL, and the [Foreign Terrorist Organization](http://www.state.gov/j/ct/rls/other/des/123085.htm) ("FTO") list, appear to work in tandem to disrupt terrorism, etc. The TEL was created for [purposes of immigration](http://rhesq.com/Terrorism/Understanding%20U.S.%20Counterterrorism%20Policy.html), probably to beef up the ability to prevent associated individuals from entering the US.

Comment: The link for TEL is pointing at University of Ohio, not the State of Ohio - please update